# If the axios request fails how do I put the error in the state? Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm making a simple ecommerce application and I want to show all the products. I use the redux toolkit and according to the documentation I can't find anywhere how to handle the error. This is my product slice:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  '/products/getProducts',
  async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/products');
    return data;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  products: [],
  product: {},
  error: '',
};

export const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'products',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getProducts.pending]: state => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getProducts.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.products = payload;
    },
    [getProducts.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = payload;
    },
  },
});

export const productsReducer = productsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[getProducts.rejected]: (state, { error }) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = error.message;
    }
```